# how to find the maximum area of a two rectangle under a parabola

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Starting from a very basic concept,  what is the largest rectangle to be drawn under the function $f(x)$ as shown in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGZkD.png). Picking an arbitrary point on the x-axis $(x, 0)$ and its mirror $(-x, 0)$ to form the width of the rectangle to be $2x$ and the height is $f(x)$ where the intersection with the function points $(\pm x,f(x))$. [*This is true provided $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $f(y)\ge f(x)$ for all $y\in [-x,x]$. AR.*]

Thus, the function that gives area of the rectangle is $A(x) = 2xf(x)$. Using the product rule for differentiation, you find the derivative of this function is

$$A'(z) = 2f(z) + 2zf'(z).$$
This is called the Jacobian matrix optimization ***(is this correct? if yes can you provide reference.)***. When you set this equation equal to zero to find the critical point(s), you obtain
$$
0 = 2f(x) + 2xf'(x) \rightarrow
-2f(x) = 2xf'(x) \rightarrow
-f(x) = xf'(x)
$$
Solving this equation for $x$ yields the critical point(s), one of which provides the dimensions for the rectangle of maximum area. [*This is true for a point $x_0$ from the interior of $\operatorname{dom} f$ such that a function $xf(x)$ has a finite derivative in some neighborhood of the point $x_0$, so you also have to consider separately points from $\operatorname{dom} f\setminus \operatorname{int}\operatorname{dom} f$. AR*]

Suppose a parabola's equation is $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. This is the equation of a parabola whose y-intercept is (27.78, 0.9772) and whose two x-intercepts are  (2.72, 0) and (52.84, 0). After shifting the function to be symmetric over the y axis the new y-intercept is (0, 0.9772) and x-intercept ($\pm 25.06$, 0). The new function looks like $f(x) = a(x+d)^2+b(x+d)+c$, where $d=27.78, a=-0.0016, b=0.086 \text{ and } c=-0.22$ for simplicity $f(x) =\bar{a}x^2+\bar{b}x+\bar{c}$.

The derivative of this function is $f'(x) = 2ax+b$. Now plug these functions into the rectangle maximization equation above to find the critical point:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&-f(x) = xf'(x) \rightarrow
\bar{a}x^2+\bar{b}x+\bar{c}= x(2\bar{a}x+\bar{b})\rightarrow
2\bar{a}x^2+x\bar{b}-\bar{c} =0\\
&x=-\frac{\bar{b} \pm \sqrt{\bar{b}^2 + 8\bar{a}\bar{c})}}{4\bar{a}} \rightarrow
\bar{x}=\pm 14.4730\rightarrow
f(x)=0.6515
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

This equation has the solutions $\bar{x}=\pm 14.4730$. The negative solution can be ignored since the parabola is symmetric. Using the critical value $\bar{x}=14.4730$, the width of the maximum-area rectangle is $2\bar{x}=2\times14.4730$. The height is found by plugging the critical point into the function $f(\bar{x})=0.6515$:

Thus, the maximum area is $2\bar{x}f(\bar{x})=2\times14.4730\times0.6515$. =  $8.8583$.

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93248/299206) answer.

---

Till here all is basic but adding another variable to x makes the problem more complex. Generalizing the Jacobin and numerical methods to find the optimal $\bar{x}$ for more than one rectangle is the target. The lower figure illustrates the concept for two different ${x}$ to obtain the max area of the rectangles. The wavy shaded area represent the first ${x}$ denoted as ${x}_2$ where the area is $2x_2f(x_2)$. The area of the strips shaded areas are function of  ${x}_1$ and ${x}_3$, where the area of the lower rectangles is $2({x}_1 -{x}_2) f({x}_1)$ and the upper rectangle is $2{x}_3(f({x}_3)-f({x}_2))$, where again $f(x) = a(x+d)^2+b(x+d)+c$. Important assumption was counted here was inhabited from the combination theorem, where our of 2 options $2^2$ possible combination. For example if the optimal $\bar{x}_1,\bar{x}_2$ were selected to get $[f(\bar{x}_1),f(\bar{x}_2)]$ = $[0.2,0.6]$ then a third option is $[0.2+0.6=08]$ could be added, zero is the forth combination. From that $f(x_3)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)$. [*Why? AR.*]

\begin{align*} 
&A(x_1,x_2,x3)= 2x_2f(x_2)+ 2(x_1 -x_2) f(x_1) +2x_3(f(x_3) -f(x_2))\\
&   =2x_2f(x_2)+ 2(x_1 -x_2) f(x_1) +2x_3(f(x_1) +f(x_2)-f(x_2))\\
&   =2x_2f(x_2)+ 2(x_1 -x_2) f(x_1) +2x_3f(x_1)\\
\\
&\frac{A'(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{x_1}=f(x_1)  + (x_1 - x_2)f'(x_1)+ x_3f'(x_1)
\\
&\frac{A'(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{x_2}=f(x_2) + x_2f'(x_2)- f(x_1)
\\
&\frac{A'(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{x_3}=f(x_1)= a(x_1 +d)^2  + b (x_1 +d) +c
\\\\
&\frac{A'(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{x_1}=a (x_1+d)^2  + x_3 (b + a (2 x_1 +2d)) + (b + a (2x_1+2d)) (x_1 - x_2)   + b (x_1 +d) + c
\\
&\frac{A'(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{x_2}=- a(x_1+d)^2 + a(x_2+d)^2+x_2(b + a(2x_2+2d))  - b(x_1 +d) + b(x2+d)
\\
&\frac{A'(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{x_3}= a(x_1 +d)^2  + b (x_1 +d) +c\\
\end{align*}

Then solving the Jacobin matrix to obtain the optimal $\bar{x}_{1,2,3}$ but unfortunately this system of equation is non-convex.  ***(The question is, is this enough to proof non-convexity )***

[*What is a non-convexity of the system of equations? What are you asking about its convexity but not about  its solution, realizing the maximum area?  AR*]

Comment: Please consider reducing your question to the essentials. Most folks here won't want to parse this many lines of brute-force algebra just for fun.

Comment: And you may wait a lot of time before a guy who calculates for fun will encounter your question.

Comment: I added some remarks and plausible corrections to your question. Please check if all is correct.

Comment: @AlexRavsky  thanks for your comments. Please refer to my paper for the answer: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X17300877